# flattening a pandas index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like the following

```
  | id  | label |
|0| 1   | foo   |
|1| 2   | baa   |
|2| 1   | baa   |
```

and I want it to change to this structure

```
  | id  | foo| baa
|0| 1   |   1| 1
|1| 2   |   0| 1
```

I used

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,4,1,1,2], 'label':['foo', 'ba', 'foo', 'baa','coo','coo']})
df = pd.crosstab(df.id, df.key)
```

but it gives a df with weird indexing

Comment: Do you want to `reset_index`? `pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['label']).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.h). You just need to add a column to use as the values column.

But you could add a "count" column that is just 1 for each row, then in the pivot table use the count aggfunc.

Like this:

```
df['count'] = 1
pd.pivot_table(df,index='id',columns='label', values='count').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
label   baa foo
id      
1       1.0 1.0
2       1.0 0.0
```

EDIT - sorry realized it looks like you want the id as a column not the index.

You can chain .reset_index() to move id to a separate column:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index='id',columns='label', values='count').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Gives you desired output:

```
label   id  baa foo
0   1   1.0 1.0
1   2   1.0 0.0
```

Comment: Your `pivot_table` is just a less straightforward way to do the `crosstab` than OP was already using ;)

Comment: Oh true! But it does get to the desired output....